# How make implicit Ordered on java.time.LocalDate

Tags: scala, implicit, java-time, localdate

I want to use `java.time.LocalDate` and `java.time.LocalDateTime` with an implicit `Ordered` like:

```
val date1 = java.time.LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1)
val date2 = java.time.LocalDate.of(2010, 10, 10)
if (date1 < date2) ...
```

`import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._` doesn't work, because `LocalDate` inherits from `Comparable<ChronoLocalDate>` instead of `Comparable<LocalDate>`.
How can I write my own imlicit Orderd to use <, <=, >, >= operators/methods to compare `LocalDate`'s?

Edit:

I found a way with use of an implicit class:

```
import java.time.{LocalDate}

object MyDateTimeUtils {
  implicit class MyLocalDateImprovements(val ld: LocalDate)
           extends Ordered[LocalDate] {
    def compare(that: LocalDate): Int = ld.compareTo(that)
  }
}

// Test

import MyDateTimeUtils._

val d1 = LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 1)
val d2 = LocalDate.of(2017, 2, 3)

if (d1 < d2) println("d1 is less than d2")
```

But I would prefer a way like Scala is doing for all Java classes which implements `Comparable<T>`. You just have to
`import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._` in your code. Scala implements it like:

```
implicit def ordered[A <% Comparable[A]]: Ordering[A] = new Ordering[A] {
  def compare(x: A, y: A): Int = x compareTo y
}
```

But unfortunately `LocalDate` implements `Comparable<ChronoLocalDate>` instead of `Comparable<LocalDate>`. I couldn't find a way to modify the above implicit ordered method to fit with `LocalDate`/`Comparable<ChronoLocalDate>`. Any idea?

Comment: Thank you for pointing our that `import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._` doesn't work, because `LocalDate` inherits from `Comparable<ChronoLocalDate>` instead of `Comparable<LocalDate>` - I'd been wondering for ages why that wasn't working!

Comment: Since Scala 2.13.0 this just works without having to define your own `Ordering`.

Answer (score 28):

You can use `Ordering.by` to create ordering for any type, given a function from that type to something that already has an Ordering - in this case, to `Long`:

```
implicit val localDateOrdering: Ordering[LocalDate] = Ordering.by(_.toEpochDay)
```

Comment: Thank's, but I want to use expressions like `if (date1 < date2)` in my programm code. With java.time.Instant for example it's possible when I `import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._`, because Instant inherits "Comparable<Instant>, but LocalDate only Comparable<ChronoLocalDate> instead of Comparable<LocalDate>.

Comment: also it seems toEpochDay is no longer available

Answer (score 26):

#### Comparing by `LocalDate.toEpochDay` is clear, though maybe relatively slow...

The [answer by @tzach-zohar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38059584/438886) is great, in that it's most obvious what is going on; you're ordering by Epoch Day:

```
implicit val localDateOrdering: Ordering[LocalDate] = Ordering.by(_.toEpochDay)
```

However, if you look at the [implementation of `toEpochDay`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/time/LocalDate.java#l1822) you'll see that it's relatively involved - 18 lines of code, with 4 divisions, 3 conditionals and a call to `isLeapYear()` - and the resulting value isn't cached, so it gets recalculated with each comparison, which might be expensive if there were a large number of `LocalDate`s to be sorted.

#### ...making use of `LocalDate.compareTo` is probably more performant...

The [implementation of `LocalDate.compareTo`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/time/LocalDate.java#l1859) is simpler - just 2 conditionals, no division - and it's what you'd be getting with that implicit conversion of [`java.lang.Comparable` to `scala.math.Ordering`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/00dac594/src/library/scala/math/Ordering.scala#L206-L208) that `scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._` offers, if only it worked! But as you said, it doesn't, because `LocalDate` inherits from `Comparable<ChronoLocalDate>` instead of `Comparable<LocalDate>`. One way to take advantage of it might be...

```
import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._

implicit val localDateOrdering: Ordering[LocalDate] =
  Ordering.by(identity[ChronoLocalDate])
```

...which lets you order `LocalDate`s by casting them to `ChronoLocalDate`s, and using the `Ordering[ChronoLocalDate]` that `scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._` gives you!

#### ...and in the end it looks best with the lambda syntax for SAM types

The [lambda syntax for SAM types](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#lambda-syntax-for-sam-types), introduced with Scala 2.12, can make really short work of constructing a `new Ordering` :

```
implicit val localDateOrdering: Ordering[LocalDate] = _ compareTo _
```

...and I think this ends up being my personal favourite! Concise, still fairly clear, and using (I think) the best-performing comparison method.

Answer (score 5):

A slight modification to the implicit `ordered` should do the trick.

```
type AsComparable[A] = A => Comparable[_ >: A]

implicit def ordered[A: AsComparable]: Ordering[A] = new Ordering[A] {
  def compare(x: A, y: A): Int = x compareTo y
}
```

Now every type which is comparable to itself or to a supertype of itself should have an `Ordering`.

Comment: Note that view-bounds (`<%`) were deprecated in Scala 2.11, so you might get complaints from the compiler about using them. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7629

Comment: @RobertoTyley You're right. I updated my solution for a world without view bounds.

Comment: I think this is the most useful answer. It addresses both `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` in one fell swoop, and also sidesteps the performance considerations of `toEpochDay`, and also solves the problems of using only `toEpochSecond` for comparing timestamps that go down to nanoseconds.

Comment: For the future reader: this modified definition is now part of the standard library since 2.13.0, so this all just works now.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution that I use:

define two implicits. The first one for making an `Ordering[LocalDate]` available. And a second one for giving `LocalDate` a `compare` method which comes in very handy. I typically put these in package objects in a library I can just include where I need them.

```
package object net.fosdal.oslo.odatetime {

  implicit val orderingLocalDate: Ordering[LocalDate] = Ordering.by(d => (d.getYear, d.getDayOfYear))

  implicit class LocalDateOps(private val localDate: LocalDate) extends AnyVal with Ordered[LocalDate] {
    override def compare(that: LocalDate): Int = Ordering[LocalDate].compare(localDate, that)
  }
}
```

with both of these defined you can now do things like:

```
import net.fosdal.oslo.odatetime._

val bool: Boolean = localDate1 < localDate1

val localDates: Seq[LocalDate] = ...
val sortedSeq = localDates.sorted
```

Alternatively... you could just use my library (v0.4.3) directly. see: https://github.com/sfosdal/oslo

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution for `java.time.LocalDateTime`

```
implicit val localDateTimeOrdering: Ordering[LocalDateTime] =
  Ordering.by(x => x.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toEpochSecond)
```

Answer (score 0):

one possible implementation in Scala 3 is to use a `Conversion`:

```scala
  given toOrderedLocalDate: Conversion[LocalDate, Ordered[LocalDate]] with
    def apply(x: LocalDate): Ordered[LocalDate] = (y: LocalDate) => x.compareTo(y)
```