# Why LocalDate doesn't implements Comparable<LocalDate>?

Tags: java, scala, implicit-conversion, comparable, localdate

**Initial Problem:**

In **Scala**, I would like to use implicit `Ordering[T]#Ops` to compare two `LocalDate`.

It just to use "operators" like `>` instead of `isAfter`.

It should be just an import: `import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._`

**Inspection:**

Looks like it works with `LocalTime` and doesn't with `LocalDate` because `LocalTime` instead of `LocalDate` implements `Comparable<LocalTime>`.

**Question:**

I wondering,

Why `LocalDate` implements `Comparable<ChronoLocalDate>` instead of  `Comparable<LocalDate>`?

Comment: It implements `Comparable<ChronoLocalDate>` as well as `ChronoLocalDate` and by implementing those two, every instance of it is of course comparable to another `LocalDate` instance.

Comment: [Link: Online demonstration that you can sort by the natural order of `LocalDate`](https://ideone.com/BTawTI)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38059191/how-make-implicit-ordered-on-java-time-localdate/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`LocalDate` in fact `implements Comparable<ChronoLocalDate>` as well as `ChronoLocalDate` and by implementing those two, every instance of it is of course comparable to another `LocalDate` instance.

You can have a look at the [JavaDocs for `LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) on Oracle's website.

[`ChronoLocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDate.html) is an interface that is implemented by different types of calendars in order to make them all comparable to each other. That is because there are [`JapaneseDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/JapaneseDate.html), [`ThaiBuddhistDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ThaiBuddhistDate.html), [`HijrahDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/HijrahDate.html) and at least one more. Totally different calendars that are all comparable to each other, which is great. `LocalTime`, on the other hand, is just a time representation with different time zones and just doesn't have to go this interface-way to be comparable to time representations of different locales.

Answer (score 4):

To make operators work, you just need another line in addition to the import, defining the desired `Ordering` (assuming Scala 2.12):

```
implicit val localDateOrdering: Ordering[LocalDate] = _.compareTo(_)
```

If you want to use it in many classes, define it in an `object` and import where necessary.